# Are TcpClient.Client.Send() and TcpClient.GetStream.Write() equivalent?

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient, send

Using the `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient`, sending data through an active connection appears to be possible in two ways:

```
' endPoint is assigned previously
Dim a as New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
a.Connect(endPoint)
Dim b as System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream
b = a.GetStream()
b.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
```

and

```
' endPoint is assigned previously
Dim a as New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
a.Connect(endPoint)
a.Client.Send(bytes)
```

Does either have a use case that the other does not suit?

Comment: Both codes will result in a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Now they won't. Excellent answer though...

Comment: Yes they would. Now after [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63850090/2), only the first code will result in a NullReferenceException.

Comment: You're nothing if not thorough. Any thoughts on the question as posed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Socket.Send and Stream.Write? (in relation to tcp ip connections)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636903/what-is-the-difference-between-socket-send-and-stream-write-in-relation-to-tcp)

Comment: It is essentially the same question, though the answer leaves me a little longing. I get the caching and indirectness, though I don't know what it means to be 'coupled' directly to the socket.

Comment: `I don't know what it means to be 'coupled' directly to the socket` - it is explained in the next sentence. Code that uses `Send` or `Receive` can only use the socket. Code that uses the network stream would also work if you give it any other type of stream.

Comment: The former returns a new NetworkStream object and assings it to the internal `m_DataStream` Field, if none was created before, then `NetworkStream.Write()` calls the same `ws2_32.dll`'s `send()` function as `TcpClient.Client.Send()` (`Client` is the same Socket).

Comment: @GSerg is that to say that in a generics and interfacing kind of way that the stream is more universal. That if I'm using the socket explicitly in my code then there is no real consequence? I'm curious if the sentence in any way suggests the socket becomes uni-directional should any one call be made to it.

Comment: @JCollins No, that sentence does not imply that. It only implies that by using the socket directly you introduce a 'hard' dependency on the Socket class specifically (become coupled with it). By using a stream, you are free to substitute the socket to any other delivery mechanism that understands streams.